# How align 2 adjacent divs horizontally WITHOUT float?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, position

I want to make 2 divs beside each other to be aligned on the same horizontal line **WITHOUT FLOATs**

I've tried Position:relative ,, but no luck

See the example below :
http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;background:#ccc;"> 
<div style="background:Blue; float:left; width:100px; height:100px;"></div> 
<div style="background:red; float:left; margin-left:100px; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

From the link above, I need the red box to be on the same line of blue box with no space below ..

**EDIT** : I want the red box to stay outside the container gray box (just as it is) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Position properties when your height and width are fixed

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;position:relative;background:#ccc;"> 
   <div style="background:Blue; position:absolute; left:0%; width:50%; height:100%;">
   </div> 
   <div style="background:red; position:absolute; left:50%; width:50%; height:100%;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this works, I was trying to stay away from absolute positions, but seems it's the most reliable method :(

Comment: good method but i wouldn't want to manage the left property every time

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Its an old post and I just modified OP's code but yeah actually no need if you dont want to. Edited to percentage as that is way better. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

#### `Relative` with `inline-block` display

---

```css
#one {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
 }

 #two {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
 }

 #three {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="one"><div id="two"></div><div id="three"></div></div>
```

**EDIT**

The code below also works fine. Here, because of comments, the line feed is commented out and ignored.

```css
#one {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
 }

 #two {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
 }

 #three {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div><!--
  --><div id="three"></div>
 </div>
```

> **Why it works** `block` displays take the whole width of their container, even if you set a very small `width`, rest of the space
>   will be taken as margin (even if you remove margin). That's just how
>   they behave. `inline-block` displays work much like `inline` displays
>   except that they do respect the `padding` etc you give them. But they
>   still ignore `margin`s (someone correct me if I am wrong). Same as
>   inline displays, if you give a line-feed between them in your `HTML`,
>   it's converted to a small space. So to remove that, Here I have the
>   HTML in a single line. If you indent the code then the `div#three`
>   will be pushed down (as you have fixed width of `div#one` so height is
>   only option.)

Comment: Sorry, It wasn't me who downvoted, but thanks really for your time & effort .. still can't solve my problem using inline-block , actually I'm building a content slider with multiple slides and I want to arrange them all side by side with a viewport that has overflow-x:hidden , but still no luck with inline-blocks :(

Comment: I just found out that `margin` does work on `inline-block`. For your slider if you change the `margin-left` of first block to `-100px`, then it will hide and you can see second block. With `absolute` you'd have to change `left` of every block if you want the sliding effect. **PS:** I didn't mean that you downvoted this answer, I was just asking the down voter, whosoever he is.

Comment: Fair enough. But I will leave it there, its not hurting anyone. If nothing else, then it might help someone in future.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid `float`, `position` and `inline-block`, here's a margin-only solution:

```
<div style="width:200px; background:#ccc;">
<div style="background:blue; width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:red; width:100px; height:100px; margin:-100px 0 0 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/XVzLK/33/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your divs on same line without floats you can use `display: inline-block;` and give some negative margin value to your div because **inline-block** contains some margin between them.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK/23/)

As your Edited question I have submitted another fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK/29/)

Or you could simply add `margin-top: -100px;` to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK/31/).

Comment: I don't think there's any margin between the `inline-block` elements. [**Read This.**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) Negative margin trick does work but it's not really margin.

Comment: The edited answer seems ok, but you had to close the container div before the red box, which is not a good option for dynamic content I think (?)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/XVzLK/22/

```
<div style="width:200px;position: relative; background:#ccc;">
<div style="background:Blue; position:absolute; top:0; left: 0; width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:red; position:absolute; top:0; right: 0; width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Setting position relative on the coloured divs makes their position relative to where they would have been in the document. I think what you wanted to do is make the containing div position relative, and the children divs positioned absolutely within it. I'm assuming that "with now space below" meant "with no space below"

There is a tutorial here that may be of use: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/