# Horizontally align div without float

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to know if there exists an *elegant* way to horizontally align 3 `divs` ***without using*** `float` css property.

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="parent">  
  <div id="first">Left</div>  
  <div id="second">Middle</div>  
  <div id="third">Right</div>
</div>
```

I ask this question because the parent `div` has not `float` property and adding `float` to children cause problems on page resizing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130711/how-align-2-adjacent-divs-horizontally-without-float

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` or `display:table-cell` with the inner content.

- ***Flex layout*** (*See also [**T J's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261471/3444240)*)***:***

```css
#parent{ display:flex; justify-content: space-between; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9CcN/451/)

- ***Table layout:***

```css
#parent{ display:table; width:100%; }
#parent div{ display:table-cell; }
#first{ text-align:left; }
#second{ text-align:center; }
#third{ text-align:right; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9CcN/)

- ***Inline-block layout :***

```css
#parent{ width:100%; white-space:nowrap; }
#parent div{ display:inline-block; width:33.3%;}
#first{ text-align:left; }
#second{ text-align:center; }
#third{ text-align:right; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9CcN/1/)

Comment: @potashin can you please tell me the how to align four divs

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid: well, it is pretty much the same, the only difference depends on how you want to align items in the container itself

Answer (score 13):

Adding to [notulysses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444240/notulysses)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261424/2333214), If ancient browser support is not an issue, you can use css3 [Flexible_boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

By applying `display:flex` the child divs will be aligned horizontally (by default)

```
#parent{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-around;
}
```

more about [flexbox @ CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

This will avoid *the white space issue with `inline-block` elements*

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9CcN/3/)

Comment: I think this is the overall better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#parent { 
    display: table; 
}

#first, #second, #third { 
    display: table-cell; 
}
```

Comment: You should add a short explanation as to why this answer will work. Please also note that inline css is not generally seen as good code. There is also no need to repeat the same HTML here in your answer, so you can just post the pure CSS as answer.

Comment: @DarkAshelin it's just for example, he can put this css into css file

Comment: Even if it was just an example, it would encourage inexperienced coders to use this "cluttered / bad way" of coding by copying what you typed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding a workaround for floating, you could also use the following fix for your "resizing problems" (at least what I think it is caused by):

After using floats, you should always clear your floats. You can do this by adding an extra `<div>` with a class.

```
<div id="parent">  
  <div id="first">Left</div>  
  <div id="second">Middle</div>  
  <div id="third">Right</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @notulysses: Can you not change the indentation styles of other people's answers when the code is perfectly readable as it is? All it will do is piss people off for no real benefit. If you're editing answers to add syntax highlighting, adding the language hint alone is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS style below :

```css
#parent div{ display: inline-block; }
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SP4th/)

Answer (score 0):

With the CSS below you can achieve your goal :

```
#parent{
 width:140px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #CCC; 
}
#first{
    width:19px;
    height : inherit;
    display:inline;
    border : 1px solid red;
}
#second{
    width:19px;
    height : inherit;
    display:inline;
    border : 1px solid green;
}
#third{
    width:19px;
    height : inherit;
    display:inline;
    border : 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAX2W/)