# Trying to align an image vertically but also float it left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertically aligned image, but also have it float left with a 10px padding.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
      <div class="headliner"><strong>blaw</strong>
      <br />blah</div>
      <div class="header_eta"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="dummy"></div>

    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="" />
    </div>    
  </div>

  <div class="footers"></div>
</div>
```

You can also check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpbu7vxu/#&togetherjs=QLRk5qPwSQ).

I can't seem to get the img to `float: left`. It seems to be centered horizontally. Once the I get the image floated left, I need to float some text to the left side of the image.

UPDATE: Something like this  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7032/files/UberRUSH_Tracking_Page-5_1.png?5766570299208136168

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity on the desired layout, ideally an image or similar of expected output to compare against. This is especially important as you have failed to state browser version so for all I know in Chrome  51.0.2704.103 its working fine, i cant tell from this description. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Something like this.  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/7032/files/UberRUSH_Tracking_Page-5_1.png?5766570299208136168

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:left` into `img-container` with `padding-left:10px;`

Like this:

```
   .img-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align:left; /* Align center inline elements */
        font: 0/0 a;
        padding-left:10px
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try `float:left`on the image, then add a div into `img-container` also floated left with a suitable margin

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="" style="float:left;"/>
  <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">Your Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Combining yours James and Suvendu I have what I need.  https://jsfiddle.net/vpbu7vxu/7/

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your desired result, you can use the following CSS code:

```
/* Positioning */
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

1. Setting `top: 50%` and `transform: translate(..., -50%)` will center your element vertically.
2. Setting `left: 0` and `transform: translate(0, ...)` will float your element horizontally to the left.

For optical reference you can check my code work in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qn3316r/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<div class="headliner"><strong>blaw</strong>
<br />blah</div>
<div class="header_eta"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="img-container-2">
<div class="img-cell">
<img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="" />
</div>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="footer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.content {height:300px; background-color:rgb(239, 65, 59);}
.header {height:60px; background-color:rgb(55, 102, 199);}
.img-container-2 {display:table; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:left;}
.img-cell {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
.headliner {padding:10px; height:50px;}
.footer {height:40px; background-color:rgb(66, 199, 123);}
</style>
```

Comment: Suvendu, combining yours and James I have what I need. Thank you!  https://jsfiddle.net/vpbu7vxu/7/

Answer (score 0):

`img-container` text align to left;

```
  text-align: left;
```

here you code

```
.img-container {
position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  /* Align center inline elements */
  font: 0/0 a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Once the I get the image floated left I need to float some text to the left side of the image.

So you will need to [align two divs horrizontaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261376/css-horizontally-align-div-without-float). For this you will need to use `display: inline-block` for both of them. By using this approach, you will need to put the image inside a div, and the text inside another div.

You could also make a `table` with the first `td` containing the text and the second `td` containing the image. Then float `table` to left.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this,
        Html code:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div  class="headliner"><strong>" blaw "</strong><br />" IS EN ROUTE "</div>
        <div  class="header_eta"></div>
      </div>

    <div  class="content">
      <div class="dummy"></div>

        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="" />
        </div>


    </div>

    <div  class="footer">sdfsd</div>
    </div>

    css:
    .content {
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: rgb(239, 65, 59);
    }

    .header {
        height: 60px;
        background-color: rgb(55, 102, 199);
    }

    .dummy {
        padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
    }

    .img-container {
    position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 10px;
      right: 0;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .img-container:before {
        content: ' ';
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .img-container img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
    }



    .headliner {
      padding:10px;
      height:50px;
    }
    .footer {
        height: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        background-color: rgb(66, 199, 123);
        text-align: left;
    }
```

you can refer a link:https://jsfiddle.net/vpbu7vxu/5/

Comment: Close but your gray image is not centered vertically. Its close.